# How to add "sudo" group

Tags: sudo, group

I've done a mistake: I've removed the 'sudo' group, because I have forgotten the -a option (I wanted to add 'video' group):

```
sudo usermod -G video $USER
```

Now, when I want to call `sudo` I have this message:

```
orangepi@orangepi:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for orangepi: 
Sorry, user orangepi is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/apt-get update' as root on orangepi.
```

I read some solution (like `visudo`, or `sudo adduser <username> sudo`) but the problem persists. I can be root with calling `su`.

Some informations:

```
orangepi@orangepi:~$ groups
orangepi video               # I would like to add sudo, groupes and others
```

visudo:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

%shutdown ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/xfce4/xfsm-shutdown-helper

# Autoriser sudo ifup sans mot de passe
orangepi  ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifup
```

How can I repair this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have become root via `su`, do:

```
adduser orangepi sudo
```

If you don't have `adduser` on your system, try with `usermod -a` to append to the groups list:

```
usermod -a -G sudo orangepi
```

You might also want to investigate which groups your user is a member of by default, and add those back as well (such as the group named after your user, `adm`, etc.).

Alternatively, you can use `su -c`:

```
su -c "adduser orangepi sudo"
```

Comment: Thanks, does it need a reboot? Because the `groups` command returns the same

Comment: @Guillaume No, the effect should be immediate. Did either command return an error?

Comment: @muru I believe it needs at least a new login for the *shell* to pick up the new group membership - not a reboot, but either a logout-login or `su -l $USER` (or `su - $USER` etc.)

Comment: @steeldriver that's true if you were to try `sg` or some command which needed that group membership, but not for the `groups` command itself.

Comment: After reboot, it works. I've added `adm` too, I havn't tried. Thanks a lot